# Change Navigation Back Button and Navigation Title for each nested navigation links inside one list?

Tags: swiftui

This is my code:

Vstack{

```
      List{

            HStack{

                NavigationLink() {
                    Text("Change your email")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("Color"))
                    
                    TextField("Email",text: $Email)
                        .padding()
                        .keyboardType(.default)
                        .background(Color.white)
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .shadow(color: Color.gray.opacity(0.1), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 2)
                    Spacer()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "rectangle.and.pencil.and.ellipsis")
                    Text("Check your email")
                        .foregroundColor(Color("Color"))
                    
                }
        

            }
```

// how can i add them ?

```
              HStack{
                NavigationLink {
                    Text("Change your password")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("Color"))
                    
                    TextField("password",text: $password)
                        .padding()
                        .keyboardType(.default)
                        .background(Color.white)
                        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                        .shadow(color: Color.gray.opacity(0.1), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 2)
                    Spacer()
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "rectangle.and.pencil.and.ellipsis")
                    Text("Check your password")
                        .foregroundColor(Color("Color"))
                    
                }
        

            }
            }
       }
```

i want to change the back button and navigation title for each navigation link!

but it is not happening inside each navigation ,it will be only done on the list itself !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

To answer your question, just put them inside of the NavigationLink.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationLink() {
        Text("Change your email")
            .font(.headline)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .foregroundColor(Color("Color"))
        
        TextField("Email",text: $email)
            .padding()
            .keyboardType(.default)
            .background(Color.white)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .shadow(color: Color.gray.opacity(0.1), radius: 5, x: 0, y: 2)
        Spacer()
            .navigationTitle("Title 2") <-- This can go on any of these views
    } label: {
        Image(systemName: "rectangle.and.pencil.and.ellipsis")
        Text("Check your email")
            .foregroundColor(Color("Color"))
        
    }
    .navigationTitle("Title 1") <-- This is for the main view
}
```

A couple of things with the code. First, the view code inside of the `NavigationLink()` really should be abstracted to its own view struct. It makes your code more readable.

Also, convention in Swift is to use lower case to start the name of a variable, upper case is reserved for types. You will notice I lowercased your `email` variable name, but if you were talking about its type, you would use `String`.